# Several similar urls redirecting (301) to a single page

Tags: redirect, mod-rewrite, apache2, wildcard, http-status-code-301

I want all of URLs matching this pattern:

> /main-url/WHATEVER-STRING-HERE >>> /new-main-url/

Observe that I want to ignore */WHATEVER-STRING-HERE*.

How could achieve this in *Apache2*, by using Redirect 301.

Somehow like?

> Redirect 301 /main-url/* /new-main-url/

With * wildcard meaning "any string" ?

I prefer not to use Rewrite if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RedirectMatch

```
RedirectMatch 301 /main-url/.* /new-main-url/
```